# How to Precisely layout div in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am stuck trying to precisely layout an element in my page. I hope someone can help me out.

Please review http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/5ssqP/2/show/.

Thanks.

**My Confused Question List:**

- I don't know why there is a space above the `dev-footer` although I have precisely calculated the height of elements (you can see what I have done in the document ready event)
- This problem is also with the table contents of the right of page
- Please try to duplicate more rows to see what happens

Thanks.

Comment: what's the question?  What do you need help with?  Are you just stuck or do you have a specific problem with your code?

Comment: @Joseph Marikle Please see the updated content . Any comments are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't have the time tonight to go through it all, but it's also a generally good idea to create a demo with your question.  Here's your code in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ssqP/. It can also be viewed like so: http://jsfiddle.net/5ssqP/show

Comment: Thanks your edit for me .I had updated my post .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do **not** use Javascript to resize these elements. Prefer to use CSS directly. This will allow you to write cleaner code which is easier to edit and performs better. In the particular case, you don't need to manually calculate the height using Javascript. Instead, utilize CSS positioning to achieve your desired results.

Specifically, set your main content div to take up all the page in height, excluding the footer and header as follows:

```css
#content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Then adjust the contents of that div to take up as much space as you'd like them to on-the-fly. For example, you want your sidebar-holder to take up the whole height of the #content div. Therefore, the following CSS code suffices:

```css
#sidebar-holder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Similarly, your "splitter" div can be positioned using CSS positioning, but it's better implemented using a CSS border:

```css
#sidebar-holder {
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

To avoid extensive and unmanageable absolute positioning, use the directive `position: relative` in your parent elements and `position:absolute` within your child elements. This technique allows you to position child elements in absolute coordinates within a box defined by their closest relative parent. Therefore, the coordinates (0, 0) correspond to the top-left corner of the parent box.

I've reproduced in your code the full behavior that you desire using CSS only and it fixes your problems directly, without messy pixel value calculations. In addition, replacing Javascript with CSS makes it behave correctly when resizing the page and does not require rerunning your jQuery code on resize events.

Comment: Very good idea,Thank you, It is so nice of you to review all the content of post .

Comment: Could you recommend some books about constructing html page to me ?thanks.

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you. An excellent book is HTMLDog. You can learn more about it at: http://www.htmldog.com/ I suggest that you review their 6 online tutorials, they're all exceptional.

Comment: Thank you, I hope I can up vote more than once.and I hope you enjoy code work and music. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough content to fill the gap between the `footer` and your `content`. If you look at the page when you don't have the screen maximized, there isn't a gap. There's plenty of ways to fix it. I would increase the `height` of the footer or increase the `min-height` of your content. Really, it's up to you.