# Precisely layout div

Tags: jquery

I found sometimes I can't precisely layout the element. you can see the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964891/how-to-precisely-layout-div-in-html). check script of the document ready event. you will see even I had already calculate the element height, But it doesn't work well. so I wonder if it is the unit problem. can anybody tell me why ? thanks.

Comment: Just read the docs, please. http://api.jquery.com/width/ http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Get functions return pixels in most cases, even if the values were defined as %, em, etc.

Comment: People who down vote this post please check the update .thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> returns a unit-less pixel

Source: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery returns values in `px`, it's in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the function. You'll need to look at the documentation to see. In this cause it is simply integers.

When settings CSS values, if you don't specify a unit, it assumes pixels.